# Angular sm-select: select all when loading

Tags: javascript, jquery, angular

I would like to select all options when loading sm-select. Is it possible to mark option as selected in *ngfor loop?

I tried to fill multipleData array in ngInit but it doesn't work for me.

Could you please help?

```js
   // My file dashboard.component.html contains

<div class="ui form">
<label for="multipleControl">Categories</label>
<sm-select *ngIf="categories" [options]="{direction: 'downward'}" [(model)]="categories"  placeholder="Kategorie..." class="fluid search multiple" (onChange)="onMultiple('categories', $event)">
<option *ngFor="let category of categories [value]="category.id">{{category.name}}</option>
</sm-select>
</div>


//My file dashboard.component.ts contains

categories: Category[];


loadCategories() {  this.influencerService.getCategories().subscribe(categories => {
      this.categories = categories;
    },
      err => {
        console.log(err);
        return false;
      }
    );
  }

  onMultiple(data: Array<Category>): void {
    this.multipleData = data;
    console.log(this.multipleData);
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a [mcve]. Use the "edit" link to improve your *question* - do not add more information via comments. Thanks!

Comment: "doesnt work" isnt a problem description we could help with.